# A simple facebook app gets Method Post is not allowed error

Tags: facebook, post, iframe, apache2

I tried a very simple helloworld example facebook app. Basically I have a webpage, only contains one file index.php, which only contains one line: echo "helloworld". I have registered this app as an facebook app, configured the setting, canvas url to http://mydomain/..

I can load the page mydomain/index.php. However, when I load the page http://apps.facebook.com/appid, I got the following error:
   The requested method POST is not allowed for the URL ...

I checked apache config, there is no  or  settings to prevent POST method.

Apache error log ad access log does not say anything.

Do you have any clue how to fix this?

Thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

The first request a Facebook app makes is a POST request.  It seems your server is not accepting them.  A common problem is having something like:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.html
```

Instead of

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php
```

Either way check your HTTP logs you will probably see an error ( possibly 405 ) with more details.